# How can I ignore leading spaces in my searchview?

Tags: java, android, searchview, textwatcher

In a normal `Edittext` I would use something like, in my `TextWatcher` method:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before,
                          int count) {

  String str = charSequence.toString();
  //if it starts with " " then don't recognise it, simply put ""
  if (str.equals(" ")) {
    Edittext.setText("");
  }
}
```

How would I do the equivalent in my `searchview`?

I am trying with things like:

```
   // listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

        String str = searchView.getQuery().toString();
        //if it starts with " " then don't recognise it, make it ""
        if (str.equals(" ")) {
          searchView.setQuery("", false);

        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try using `.trim()` method on your string. It removes unnecessary white spaces.

Comment: `if (str.equals(" ")) {
          str.trim();` doesn't acheive it, still takes leading spaces.

Comment: Use it here: `String str = searchView.getQuery().toString().trim();`. "      abc   " will be "abc" afterwards.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  The title suggests that you want to ignore leading spaces.  But the comments and code suggest you want to remove or reject them.  Which is it?  Ignore, remove or reject?   (Note: reading the existing comments and answer, I think they have assumed that you mean "ignore".)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

        String str = searchView.getQuery().toString().trim();
        //if it starts with " " then don't recognise it, make it ""
        if (str.equals("")) { 
          searchView.setQuery("", false);

        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working, still leading spaces can be typed in my searchview. I would have thought it would work. However, I think your code would trim trailing spaces also - which I want to keep.

Comment: Maybe you can do `Character ch= searchView.getQuery().charAt(0)` `if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\r'){...}`

Answer (score 0):

SearchView is a LinearLayout, so find inside it an EditText and set textChangedListener:

```
    fun SearchView.ignoreLeadingWhiteSpaces(){
       findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text).apply {
         doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if(text?.startsWith(" ") == true) {
                setText(text?.trim())
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

call:

```
searchView.ignoreLeadingWhiteSpaces()
```